# Should you be accessing another domain's repository layer in a different domain's service layer?

Tags: spring-boot, domain-driven-design, microservices

I have 2 domain's, Domain A and Domain B. Each domain has their own controller, service and repository layer in the spring boot project. Would it be wrong to have Service A make a call to Repository B's data? Does this break any form of DDD or microservice architecture?

Answer (score 2):

When the Controller is bypassing the Service this organization is often called a *relaxed layered architecture*, as layers are allowed to skip around their adjacent neighbor(s):

[image: Relaxed layered architecture]

According to [Clean Architecture](http://www.informit.com/store/clean-architecture-a-craftsmans-guide-to-software-structure-9780134494166), chapter 34:

> bypassing the business logic layer is undesirable, especially if that
>   business logic is responsible for ensuring authorized access to
>   individual records, for example

and

> Web controllers should never access repositories directly

So in your case `Service A` should not be able to make a call to `Repository B`'s data directly. All communication should be done via `Controller B`.